# Teams interoperability with ACS using automatic recording

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, acs, microsoft-teams-js

We have a need to schedule/record meetings in our application.  We decided to use Microsoft Teams for the underlying technology for this.

We created a service account that has its own policy based recording that will let users in without a lobby and auto start a recording (using graphApi to create the online meeting with recordAutomatically set to True) .  Participants and organization agents join this, conduct their session and exit.  This seems to work well, however, because of privacy concerns, if a user elects rejoin the meeting, they have access to the recording (through chat) which we can’t have.

We implemented a solution with Azure Communication Service that integrates with the teams meeting (https://azure.github.io/communication-ui-library/?path=/docs/composites-call-with-chat-jointeamsmeeting--join-teams-meeting) to have its own user experience, so the recording will now show to download.

This seems to work, however the issue we’re running into is with the automatic recording.  If I join the teams meeting through a teams client, it automatically starts recording, but if I join through the ACS client, the recording doesn’t start.

I looked for graphApi’s to auto start a meeting but couldn’t find any.  Is there a solution for this type of scenario?

Comment: Automatic recording of meetings is allowed when joined through a Teams client, but this functionality is not available when joining through an ACS client.

Comment: is there a way to have a bot or automate someone to join that meeting so the recording can start?

Comment: No there isn't any.

Comment: wouldn't this work? Set-SPOTenant -BlockDownloadFileTypePolicy $true -BlockDownloadFileTypeIds TeamsMeetingRecording  we just need to be able to prevent the downloading of file to the local computer

Comment: Yes, this can be used to block the download of Teams meeting recording files from SharePoint or OneDrive.